# Can I animate a canvas behind a button and draw pixels?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a HTML button that will animate some 1 to 2 pixels squares. I have done the similar thing in Ruby (Ruby2D):

[image: Ruby2D Sample]

[[Source Code](https://pastebin.com/jchBtUtc)]

Due to my lack of understanding of HTML, I have only created the button:

```html
<!Doctype HTML>

<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Button Particles</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 </head>

 <body style="background-color: #000">
  <a><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Souravgoswami/HTMLProjects/master/Project%206%20-%20Our%20Lovely%20Course%20%5BHTML%2C%20CSS%2C%20JQuery%2C%20Bootstrap%5D/assets/img/down-arrow.svg?sanitize=true" class="centre-img" width="100px" height="100px"></a>

  <script>
   // Position elements of class centre-img to centre of the screen
   var centreElements = document.getElementsByClassName('centre-img')
   for (let i = 0 ; i < centreElements.length ; ++i) {
    var el = centreElements[i].style

    el.position = 'absolute'
    el.left = '50%'
    el.top = '50%'
    el.margin = `-${centreElements[i].width / 2}px 0px 0px -${centreElements[i].offsetHeight / 2}px`
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

How do I create a canvas to animate the particles under the button?

Comment: I have posted this question some days ago, and received some downvotes. Because it's a very basic thing, I wrote the answer myself and hope it helps others...

Answer (score 2):

To animate the particles, you first need to create a canvas. It's a lot of modification to your code. In order to create the same effects, here's a sample code that I have written.

### Code

```js
// Position elements of class centre-img to centre of the screen
var centreElements = document.getElementsByClassName('centre-img')
for (let i = 0 ; i < centreElements.length ; ++i) {
  var el = centreElements[i].style

  el.position = 'absolute'
  el.left = '50%'
  el.top = '50%'
  el.margin = `-${centreElements[i].width / 2}px 0px 0px -${centreElements[i].offsetHeight / 2}px`
}

// Set the FPS (FPS), number of stars (N), and the fading of the particles (fading)
var FPS = 60, N = 1500, fading = 0.025

// Star Class
class Star {
  constructor(x, y, size, opacity) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.size = size

    var a = Math.random() * 2 + 0.5, b = Math.random() * 2 + 0.5
    this.xspeed = Math.random() < 0.5 ? a * -1 : a
    this.yspeed = Math.random() < 0.5 ? b * -1 : b

    this.r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
    this.g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
    this.b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)

    this.opacity = opacity
  }
}

// Draw Background Stars in a Separate Canvas for Simplicity
var stars = [], fPS = 1000 / FPS
var canvasBG = document.getElementById('background')
var interval = null

function drawBG() {
  if(interval) clearInterval(interval)
  var ctxBG = canvasBG.getContext('2d')
  var bgStars = []

  canvasBG.width = window.innerWidth
  canvasBG.height = window.innerHeight

  for(let i = 0 ; i < 250 ; ++i)
    bgStars[i] = new Star(Math.random() * canvasBG.width, Math.random() * canvasBG.height, Math.random() *2 + 1, 1)

  interval = setInterval(() => {
    ctxBG.clearRect(0, 0, canvasBG.width, canvasBG.width)

    for(let i = 0 ; i < 250 ; ++i) {
      var bS = bgStars[i]
      ctxBG.fillStyle = `rgba(${bS.r},${bS.g},${bS.b},${Math.random() > 0.05 ? 1 : 0})`
      ctxBG.fillRect(bS.x, bS.y, bS.size, bS.size)
    }
  }, fPS * 20)
}

// Draw Particles on Button
var canvas = document.getElementById('starfield')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight

var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
var btnRect = btn.getBoundingClientRect(), btnTouched = false

btn.onmouseover = () => { btnTouched = true }
btn.onmouseout = () => { btnTouched = false }

function appendStars() {
  for (let i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i)
    stars[i] = new Star(Math.random() * canvas.width,Math.random() * canvas.height,Math.random() * 2, 0)
}

drawBG()
appendStars()

window.onresize = () => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight
  btnRect = document.getElementById('btn').getBoundingClientRect()
  drawBG()
  appendStars()
}

setInterval(() => {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' )
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height )

  for (let i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i) {
    var star = stars[i]

    star.x += Math.sin(i) + star.xspeed
    star.y += Math.cos(i) + star.yspeed

    if (star.x < btnRect.x || star.x > btnRect.right || star.y < btnRect.y || star.y > btnRect.bottom)
      star.opacity -= fading

    if (star.x > canvas.width || star.x < -star.size || star.y > canvas.height || star.y < -star.size) {
      var randSize = Math.random() * 2 + 1

      stars[i] = new Star(
        btnRect.x + btnRect.width / 2 - randSize / 2,
        btnRect.y + btnRect.height / 2- randSize / 2,
        randSize, btnTouched ? 1 : 0
      )
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${star.r}, ${star.g}, ${star.b}, ${star.opacity})`
    ctx.fillRect(star.x, star.y, star.size, star.size )
  }
}, fPS)
```

```html
<!Doctype HTML>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Button Particles</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 </head>

 <body style="background-color: #000">
  <canvas id="starfield" style="position: fixed"></canvas>
  <canvas id="background" style="position: fixed"></canvas>
  <a><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Souravgoswami/HTMLProjects/master/Project%206%20-%20Our%20Lovely%20Course%20%5BHTML%2C%20CSS%2C%20JQuery%2C%20Bootstrap%5D/assets/img/down-arrow.svg?sanitize=true" id="btn" class="centre-img" width="100px" height="100px"></a>
       </body>
</html>
```

Now this should work quite efficiently because we are creating an array made up of some thousands of instances of Star class. As you can see the instance of Star class is very lightweight. After the array is created, we are looping through the items as we are drawing on the canvas.

The code can also be found [here](https://pastebin.com/6v6yq5cu).

---

### Tested Browsers

The above code has been tested on

1. Mozilla Firefox 72.0b5.
2. Chromium 79.0.3945.88 Arch Linux
3. falkon 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it's a simple animation for a button that I have re-created from a bunch of ads I have seen:
(Sorry for the messy code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
            <title>Animated Button (simple)</title>
            <style>
                            button {
                            background-color: lime;
                            color: white;
                            border: none;
                            border-radius: 8px;
                            padding: 10px 14px;
                            font-size: 12px;
                            }
            </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script>
btn = document.createElement("button"); //create a button
document.body.appendChild(btn); //display button
btn.setAttribute("onclick","alert('Clicked')") //alert onclick
go(); //run go
function go() { //defines go
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "C";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "Cl";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "Cli";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "Clic";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "Click";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "Click M";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "Click Me";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "Click Me!";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "Click Me";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "Click M";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "Click";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "Clic";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "Cli";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "Cl";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "C";
setTimeout(function() {
btn.innerHTML = "";
go(); //run go again
}, 300);
}, 300)
}, 300)
}, 300);
}, 300);
}, 300);
}, 300);
}, 300);
}, 300);
}, 300);
}, 300);
}, 300);
}, 300);
}, 300);
}, 300);
}, 300);
}
```